# Failed to run the model using metagraph tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have tried loading the model in the program so that I can run it in real time.
The following is the way I am trying:
saver =

```
tf.train.import_meta_graph(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path)+".meta")
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
outputs = graph.get_operation_by_name('output')
native = graph.get_operation_by_name('input')
sess  = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())   
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer()) 
if(tf.train.checkpoint_exists(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))):
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))
    print(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path) + "Session Loaded for Testing")
```

And I am trying to get the output as:

```
y_test_output= sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={native: x_test})
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing_reality.py", line 90, in <module>
    main()
  File "testing_reality.py", line 62, in main
    handle_client_connection(client_sock)
  File "testing_reality.py", line 45, in handle_client_connection
    y_train_pred= sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={native: x_test})
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1095, in _run
    'Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: ' + e.args[0])
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a Operation into a Tensor.
```

Please let me know what I am missing in this scenario.
Using the latest version of Tensorflow '1.12.0' on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keys` in the `feed_dict` have to be placeholders. The error states that you are using an `Operation` as a key in the `feed_dict`. In case the `input` variable is indeed a `placeholder` then load it in the following way:

```
native = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
```

The same goes for the `outputs`:

```
outputs = graph.get_tensor_by_name("output:0")
```

Comment: Thank you for making me understand what is the error. Can you tell me how I can improve it? Is it possible to get the input variable from the Metagraph?

Comment: I have the X as input while training. `X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs],name="input")` Now while restoring the model I am trying what I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: I am getting this when I tried it again: `>>> native = graph.get_operation_by_name('input')
>>> native
<tf.Operation 'input' type=Placeholder>`. You see it is placeholder.

Comment: Did you run `native = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input")`?

Comment: Thank you it worked. I used `native = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")`